Basics of geodesic fiber winding vs isotensoids in pressure vessel construction (with focus on future habitats in space)
Background:
TechCrunch's July 27, 2024 Max Space reinvents expandable habitats with a 17th-century twist, launching in 2026 references isotensoids several times.
I can find mention of isotensoid in the following Wikipedia pages:

Mars atmospheric entry; Technologies
Reinforced rubber; Composite reinforced structure
Ballute; Design
Inflatable; Structural inflatables

but I still don't have a good clear idea what an isotensoid actually is.
Searching lead me to Guo et al. (2020) Design of winding pattern of filament-wound composite pressure vessel with unequal openings based on non-geodesics where the introduction nicely but briefly introduces geodesic winding patterns but only to discuss their limitations and all the newer non-geodesic winding patterns and algorithms.

To broaden the designability, the non-geodesics winding is more and more used in the filament winding on complex parts. By employing the friction between the filament bundles and its supporting surface, the non-geodesics significantly enlarge the available winding path.

So far, I have found that in mathematics, a geodesic of a surface is not necessarily the shortest path between a pair of given points A and B. It seems to be more of a natural path or some kind of trajectory that can be found with an ordinary differential equation (ODE) solver, perhaps in some way similar to how we might integrate the trajectory of a spacecraft.
Wikipedia's Geodesic; introduction; examples includes the following image, which seems to be nothing to do with finding the shortest path. I have a hunch that it's actually a closed path but I can't tell.
 Source click for larger

Transpolar geodesic on a triaxial ellipsoid, case A. Vital statistics: a:b:c = 1.01:1:0.8, β1 = 90°, ω1 = 39.9°, α1 = 180°, s12/b ∈ [−232.7, 232.7], orthographic projection from φ = 40°, λ = 30°. The geodesic is found by solving the ordinary differential equations for the free motion of a particle constrained to the surface of the ellipsoid; the solution is carried out in Cartesian coordinates.

Question:
Isotensoids and geodesics both seem to be mathematical concepts and tools related to construction of pressure vessels, including those for spaceflight. While geodesic fiber winding seems to be passé, the TechCrunch article suggests that there will be isotensoid pressure vessels in Earth orbit in a few years, with one long-term development target being habitable structures for people.
Is it possible to explain the basics of geodesic fiber winding vs isotensoids in pressure vessel construction in the form of a nice Stack Exchange answer in such a way that I'd be able to use each in a sentence and not sound confused?
For the geodesic trajectory what does "the ordinary differential equations for the free motion of a particle constrained to the surface" actually mean? For example, if I make a hollow ellipsoid in zero gravity and put a tiny ball bearing inside it and give it a kick - is its trajectory that of a geodesic?

Potentially helpful:

How do you find a geodesic on an ellipsoid?
How do I get geographic coordinates of a point if I know the distance from two other points? specifically @PM2Ring's hefty answer
Zu et al. (2014) Development of Filament Wound Composite Isotensoidal Pressure Vessels "... isotensoid-based design leads to uniform fiber tension throughout the whole shell and the resulting structure can thus be considered as optimal for a pressure vessel"
Guo et al. (2020) Design of winding pattern of filament-wound composite pressure vessel with unequal openings based on non-geodesics


https://www.mdpi.com/2504-477X/5/2/56   potentially helpful too

@user721108 yes indeed, thanks!

all shortest paths are geodesics, but not all geodesics are shortest paths. any local extremum of path length will do.  on a sphere, geodesics are great circles: from one point to another, taking the long way around the circle is just as much a geodesic as taking the short way. on a cylinder, geodesics are helical. the shortest path goes from one point to another without winding around the whole cylinder, but every helix connecting the two points, each one wrapping around the cylinder a different integer number of times, is equally a geodesic.

the differential equation definition of a geodesic is "a curve that parallel transports its own tangent vector" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport . In general relativity, a freely falling particle (one acted upon only by gravity, not any other forces) travels along a geodesic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity . in the ball bearing case, however, the force that constrains it to move only on the surface does not constrain it to follow only geodesic curves. some constraints can be interpreted as geodesic, but not all, or even most.

I would be delighted to help you with differential geometry in pure math and Lagrangian mechanics, but I've left these remarks as comments, not an answer, because I had never heard of an "isotensoid" before reading your question. my wild guess is geodesic winding sounds more likely to produce a gridlike structure (like lines of rational slope on a torus), while non-geodesic windings would fill in the gaps in a more ergodic fashion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity .

@RyanC All good stuff! Space SE is one of those "nice" SE sites that still welcomes partial answers that bring some insight to the question, so please, please feel free to move these to a geodesic-centric answer! "a curve that parallel transports its own tangent vector" is one of those "Aha!" insights that belong in an answer post for reasons of visibility to future readers.

@RyanC I have a hunch though that within a few days you're going to become a master of "isotensoidology" Seeing as how it comes from "Bernoulli’s 1694 'Curvatura Laminae Elasticae'", how can one resist?!  :-)

"I have a hunch that it's actually a closed path" No, it isn't closed. Ellipsoid of revolution geodesics in general aren't closed, apart from the purely meridional ones, and the equator. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid#Behavior_of_geodesics That article was mostly written by Charles Karney, who created the ellipsoid geodesic diagram in your question. Dr Karney is the author of GeographicLib, which uses polynomial approximations to do fast but accurate ellipsoid geodesic computations. (Precise calculations require elliptic integrals, so they're a little slower).

Sorry, I know nothing about isotensoids, but I'm a fan of tensegrity structures. :) On a vaguely related note, I was recently exploring the gyroid, which is a minimal surface, so its mean curvature is zero everywhere. I have an interactive 3D one here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65883430#65883430 It's a bit slow to render initially because its built with elliptic integrals. Also https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65837249#65837249

@PM2Ring If a geodesic (as defined at least in some places) is "found by solving the ordinary differential equations for the free motion of a particle constrained to the surface of the ellipsoid" and an ODE solver could be initialized with any (in this case 4D) state vector, then it seems a closed geodesic would be readily achievable. Can you do more than assert that it can't? Can you cite a source?

As Karney says in that first link (to Behavior of geodesics) "For nearly all values of α0, the geodesic will fill that portion of the ellipsoid between the two vertex latitudes (see Fig. 9)". α0 is the initial heading (azimuth) of the path. Yes, for some values of α0 the path will return to its starting point, with the same heading, after some finite number of laps, but generally it will wrap indefinitely between the two vertex latitudes.

@PM2Ring "...examples includes the following image, which seems to be nothing to do with finding the shortest path. I have a hunch that it's actually a closed path..." My singular "it" refers to the singular subject of the immediately proceeding sentence. I'm not talking about all geodesics or some definition, I'm only talking about the one that is depicted in the image, and in this case the initial and final points are coincident. So my hunch is that your "No, it isn't closed" may not be correct, assuming your "it" is my "it".

I'm just quoting Karney, who computed those diagrams. OTOH, your diagram is of a triaxial ellipsoid, but the stuff I quoted is about ellipsoids of revolution. However, since ellipsoids of revolution are rather simpler than triaxials, I expect that geodesics on a triaxial are even worse-behaved than those on an ellipsoid of revolution.

I have no proof, and I'm certainly no expert in differential geometry. But I assume it's like Lissajous curves: only special (rational) combinations produce curves of finite length. General curves fill a subset of their space.

@PM2Ring I'm sure that's right, and I'll bet a hundred Quatloo that the illustration I've linked to from Wikimedia s a representation of a closed one. Would you like to raise me? :-)

I've just spent a day learning a little bit about geodesics on triaxial ellipsoids (previously, I only skimmed that section of the wiki article). I've just computed that geodesic (transpolar case A) in SageMath (using numerical integration). The end point is quite close to the start point, and so are the associated tangent vectors, but they aren't identical. BTW, the quatloo is standard currency in the Python room. ;)

@PM2Ring Excellent! :-) There are only a certain number of digits displayed in the text, and all ODE solvers accumulate errors for a few different reasons, so I'll raise my wager to four hundred Quatloos!

Sure, numerical integration has errors, as we know well from computing orbits. I didn't implement an integrator, I just used https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/riemannian_geometry/sage/geometry/riemannian_manifolds/parametrized_surface3d.html#sage.geometry.riemannian_manifolds.parametrized_surface3d.ParametrizedSurface3D.geodesics_numerical which uses one of Sage's standard ODE solvers (and it doesn't use arbitrary precision arithmetic). But the difference in the endpoints is much larger than the error that I expect from that integrator.

Also, it would be a bit strange (IMHO) for Karney to emphasise that only certain geodesics are closed to then post a closed example without mentioning it. FWIW, I just noticed that he recently posted a brief answer about triaxial geodesics: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4913010/207316 That's about the inverse problem: finding the geodesic between two specified points, which is much harder than the direct problem, because you don't know the initial azimuth direction.

I know nothing about isotensoids, so I can't address that part of your question, but I can give some general information about geodesics and winding patterns, and geodesics on ellipsoids in particular.
The Wikipedia geodesic article has a lot of good information, but much of it is rather technical, partly because it tries to be very general, and because it covers geodesics in the curved 4D spacetime of General Relativity, not just the simpler case of geodesics on a curved 2D surface embedded in flat 3D Euclidean space. I'll try to simplify that information, but parts of this answer assume that the reader has some familiarity with the basics of multivariable calculus. I'm certainly no expert in differential geometry, but hopefully I won't make any major blunders. ;)
Introduction
Let's start with an informal definition. Wikipedia says

a geodesic is a curve representing in some sense the shortest path between two points on a surface. [...] It is a generalization of the notion of a "straight line".

On a flat plane, all straight lines are geodesics. On a sphere, the geodesics are the great circles, those circles whose centre is the centre of the sphere. So there are an infinite number of geodesics connecting any pair of antipodal points on a sphere, eg the north and south poles.
The basic concept is that a geodesic is a natural path on a surface. A particle following a geodesic is constrained to move on the surface, but is otherwise subject to no forces. You start at some point on the surface, choose a direction, and start walking forward, following the curvature of the surface. If you "zoom in" sufficiently, the patch of surface that you're standing on looks and feels like a plane. As you move forward you take the shortest path to your next point, so the geodesic is locally the shortest path between the points comprising it.
But it's not necessarily the shortest path between two points. For example, on the Earth, the geodesic from London to Paris is (approximately) an arc of a great circle. If you head east from London to Paris along that geodesic, it is the shortest path. But if you head west from London following that great circle, going all the way around the Earth, your path is still a geodesic. It's certainly longer than the eastward path, but at each step it's locally the shortest path between all the points on your journey.
Ryan C gives a nice example in the comments.

On a cylinder, geodesics are helical. The shortest path goes from one point to another without winding around the whole cylinder, but every helix connecting the two points, each one wrapping around the cylinder a different integer number of times, is equally a geodesic.

Wikipedia has a cute GIF anim illustrating a non-trivial geodesic path on a torus (created by Hamishtodd1). Unfortunately, it's >2 MB, so I can't upload it here, so I have to hotlink it (and hope it won't get changed too much).


If an insect is placed on a surface and continually walks "forward", by definition it will trace out a geodesic.

Mechanically, we can find a geodesic between two points by connecting the points by a thread and pulling the thread tight, taking care to ensure that the thread actually remains on the surface. That's easy enough if the surface is convex. If the surface has concave regions, we may need to get a little creative.
Closed geodesic circuits are natural winding patterns. If you wrap a (uniform) elastic thread around a convex surface, pull the thread tight, and join its ends together, tension will pull the thread into a geodesic circuit, assuming the thread can move freely, and assuming that the thread doesn't just fall off. ;)
Calculating such circuits can be slightly tricky because the tangent at the end of the circuit must be identical to the tangent at the start of the circuit. But I'm jumping ahead of the story...
Let's (temporarily) give our surface a gravity field. We want each local patch on the surface to feel flat, so the surface normal at each point (i.e., the normal to the tangent plane at that point) is our vertical direction. Globally, the gravity on the Earth is like that, but of course locally we have non-flat regions. But a sphere or ellipsoid covered with water would have gravity like that.
If you place a ball anywhere on this surface it just sits there. But a ball rolling with uniform speed on the surface follows a geodesic. Similarly, if you drive along a geodesic at uniform speed on this surface, you feel no lateral acceleration, only vertical acceleration, in the direction of the surface normal.

A mathematical interlude
I need to introduce a little bit of mathematics. A surface is two dimensional, so any point on the surface can be given a pair of coordinates, known as local coordinates. On a sphere or ellipsoid, we typically use some form of latitude and longitude as the local coordinates. On a general surface, a common convention is to use $u$ and $v$ to denote the local coordinates.
We can then define the surface by giving a set of equations connecting those local coordinates with the usual $x,y,z$ coordinates of 3D Euclidean space.
For example, for an ellipsoid of revolution with $X$ and $Y$ radius $a$ and $Z$ radius $b$, using $\beta$ for parametric latitude and $\omega$ for longitude, we get:
$$\begin{align}
x & = a\cos(\beta)\cos(\omega)\\
y & = a\cos(\beta)\sin(\omega)\\
z & = b\sin(\beta)\\
\end{align}$$
The first and second partial derivatives of those equations capture the metric properties of the surface. To find geodesics, we need to be able to determine distances, and to minimise them. Let $s$ be the arc length of some curve. The differential form of Pythagoras' theorem in 3 dimensions is simply
$$ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$$
(Those are squared first  derivatives). $ds$ is called the line element. We can write the line element in terms of the local coordinates:
$$ds^2 = E d\beta^2 + 2F d\beta d\omega + G d\omega^2$$
where
$$\left(\begin{array}{rr}
E & F \\
F & G
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{rr}
g_{11} & g_{12} \\
g_{21} & g_{22}
\end{array}\right)$$
is the metric tensor. That expression for $ds^2$ is called the first fundamental form, and $(E, F, G)$, the coefficients of the first fundamental form, are computed from the partial derivatives of the equations for the surface. The process is straightforward, but it's simpler to let SageMath do it. ;)
$$\begin{align}
g_{11} & = b^{2} \cos^2\left(\beta\right) + a^{2} \sin^2\left(\beta\right)\\
g_{12} & = 0\\
g_{21} & = 0\\
g_{22} & = a^{2} \cos^2\left(\beta\right)\\
\end{align}$$
This metric is relatively simple, due to rotational symmetry, and because our local coordinates are orthogonal: latitude and longitude lines always meet at right angles.
We can find distances on the surface by integrating equations involving first derivatives. But we want to minimise distances, so equations for geodesics involve second derivatives. Also, geodesics are intimately related to curvature, which is a function of the first and second derivatives. (Curvature is defined as the rate of change of the angle of the curve's tangent with respect to the curve's arc length. I have a brief derivation here).
I'll jump over the messy details and just state the geodesic equation. ;)
Let $\gamma(t)$ be a geodesic curve parameterised by arc length. Wikipedia uses $t$ instead of $s$. You can think of the $t$ as time, and we're traversing the curve at constant unit speed.
Then the geodesic equation, (using the Einstein summation convention) is
$$\frac{d^2\gamma^\lambda}{dt^2} = -\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\lambda \frac{d\gamma^\mu}{dt} \frac{d\gamma^\nu}{dt}$$
where the $\gamma^\lambda$ are the local coordinates of the curve, and the $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\lambda$ are the Christoffel symbols of the surface. These symbols are related to the coefficients of the first fundamental form and their partial derivatives.
We have a 2D surface, so $(\mu, \nu, \lambda)$ take on the values $(1, 2)$. For our ellipsoid, $\gamma^1 = \beta$ and $\gamma^2 = \omega$.
There are 8 Christoffel symbols, but some of them are zero, and due to the symmetry of second derivatives, $\Gamma_{ij}^k = \Gamma_{ji}^k$.
We can get SageMath to compute the Christoffel symbols:
$$\begin{align}
\Gamma_{11}^1 & = \frac{{\left(a^{2} - b^{2}\right)} \cos\left(\beta\right) \sin\left(\beta\right)}{b^{2} \cos^2\left(\beta\right) + a^{2} \sin^2\left(\beta\right)}\\
\Gamma_{11}^2 & = 0\\
\Gamma_{12}^1 & = 0\\
\Gamma_{12}^2 & = -\frac{\sin\left(\beta\right)}{\cos\left(\beta\right)}\\
\Gamma_{21}^1 & = 0\\
\Gamma_{21}^2 & = -\frac{\sin\left(\beta\right)}{\cos\left(\beta\right)}\\
\Gamma_{22}^1 & = \frac{a^{2} \cos\left(\beta\right) \sin\left(\beta\right)}{b^{2} \cos^2\left(\beta\right) + a^{2} \sin^2\left(\beta\right)}\\
\Gamma_{22}^2 & = 0\\
\end{align}$$
Einstein notation is nice and compact, but it can be a bit confusing if you aren't used to it, so I'll expand the geodesic equation to make it a bit easier to read.
Let
$$\frac{d\beta}{dt} = p$$
and
$$\frac{d\omega}{dt} = q$$
Then
$$\frac{dp}{dt} = -\left(\Gamma_{11}^1 p^2 + 2 \Gamma_{12}^1 pq + \Gamma_{22}^1 q^2\right)$$
and
$$\frac{dq}{dt} = -\left(\Gamma_{11}^2 p^2 + 2 \Gamma_{12}^2 pq + \Gamma_{22}^2 q^2\right)$$
Note that for our ellipsoid, half of those terms are zero.
We can use those last four equations to compute a geodesic, given an initial $(\beta, \omega)$ position and initial values for $p$ & $q$. We can compute $p$ & $q$ from the azimuth (heading) of the geodesic, with the help of the first fundamental form.
There are numerous ways to define azimuth. The common modern convention measures
azimuth clockwise from the north meridian. Thus north has azimuth = 0°, east = 90°, south = 180°, west = 270°. Azimuth is often represented by the letter $\alpha$. If our desired azimuth is $\alpha$ then the vector $A = (\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha)$ points in the correct direction, but we need to scale it so that its first fundamental form equals 1. That is, we need to divide the components of $A$ by
$$\sqrt{E\cos^2\alpha + 2F\cos\alpha\sin\alpha + G\sin^2\alpha}$$
to get the tangent vector $(p, q)$.
So now we (finally!) have everything we need to compute geodesics. Here's a small demo using SageMath. We compute a simple closed geodesic on an oblate ellipsoid. There are approximate parameters for this geodesic on the Wikipedia Geodesics on an ellipsoid page. See fig 11 & fig 12.
Sage can compute geodesics with an accuracy on the order of 1e-6 or better, using standard numerical integration techniques for solving an IVP (initial value problem). Its library code is reasonably fast because the bulk of the arithmetic is done using compiled code. My demo code does the integration using Python, so it's much slower. And it uses a much larger integration step size, so it's not very accurate. But it's accurate enough to demonstrate that the calculations are on-track. You can set sub_points to a larger value to improve the accuracy, but it will take longer to run.
I use synchronised Leapfrog integration (aka velocity Verlet). It's easy to implement, and to read. I didn't want to clutter the code with a more sophisticated integrator. The code could easily be optimised by removing the terms where the Christoffel symbols are zero. I retained those terms to keep the code general, and to make it clear what it's doing.
I should mention that it's possible to solve the geodesic equation for the ellipsoid of revolution using elliptic integrals, but the procedure is somewhat more complicated.

The inverse geodesic problem and geodesic circuits
The previous section shows how to solve the direct geodesic problem. The inverse geodesic problem, finding a geodesic connecting two given points, is a bit tricky because we don't know the azimuth or the length, except in special cases. So we need to make an initial estimate of the azimuth and length, and then use a numerical technique (like the multivariable version of the Newton-Raphson method) applied to the direct geodesic problem to iteratively refine the azimuth and length estimates and compute the geodesic path. Newton's method usually converges quite rapidly, unless we're in the vicinity of multiple solutions, eg when the points are nearly antipodal. We can create the initial estimate by solving the equivalent problem on the parametric sphere.
A closed simple geodesic is one that returns to its starting point with the same azimuth, without crossing over itself. On an ellipsoid of revolution, generally the only closed simple geodesics are the meridians and the equator. On a triaxial ellipsoid (all three axes of different lengths), the only closed simple geodesics are the three principle ellipses where the XYZ coordinate planes cut the ellipsoid. On a highly oblate ellipsoid there may be additional closed simple geodesics which oscillate around the equator, like the one illustrated in my demo code above.
To create winding patterns we need to find closed geodesic circuits that wrap around the ellipsoid multiple times. Such circuits are closely related to Lissajous patterns. These are easy enough to find on an ellipsoid of revolution (using Newton's method) because we can exploit its rotational symmetry. They are much harder to find on a triaxial ellipsoid.
The example given in the OP is almost a perfect circuit, but the geodesic corresponding to the quoted parameters doesn't quite return to its start point. I used Newton's method to refine those parameters so that it does return to the start point, with an error of ~2° × 1e-5 in the latitude. But the error in the azimuth is ~0.2°. FWIW, the improved parameters are $\omega_1$ = 39.888419, length = 465.30975428223; the other parameters are unchanged.
In practice, that 0.2° error is probably not an issue: we just wind the pattern, and let tension pull the thread into place.

Scriptorium
Here is a SageMath script for computing geodesics on a triaxial ellipsoid. It uses Jacobi's coordinates, as used in the Wikipedia article, Geodesics on an ellipsoid. It has a simple GUI for entering the parameters, and for selecting which components of the globe you want to display. It can take a little while to compute the first geodesic for a given ellipsoid, but it's faster when computing additional geodesics. It comes with a small collection of parameters for various geodesics, on both triaxial ellipsoids, and on a few ellipsoids of revolution.
Here is a script that uses exact integration via elliptic integrals to compute geodesics on an ellipsoid of revolution. It uses geodetic latitude, not parametric latitude. Sorry, this one has no GUI, you need to edit the script to set the parameters. But it's more accurate than the previous script, and it uses arbitrary precision arithmetic.
Finally, here's the script I used to compute the first fundamental form coefficients and the Christoffel symbols.

There's nothing better than a mathematical interlude - this is wonderful!

@uhoh Glad you like it. :)

although I don't understand them, I like Oliver Knill's videos You might appreciate this short: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/bYtjBADtcH4?feature=share
